# Why vertical spacing discrepancy with parskip for paragraph command?

Tags: spacing, windows, sections-paragraphs, linux, parskip

I have a LaTeX document that contains something similar to the code below. When I compile with `pdflatex` on Windows and Linux, there is extra vertical space just before the `\paragraph` command on the Linux version.

```
  \hrule height 1pt
  \vspace{0.05in}
  \begin{center}
    {\Large \textbf{My Document}}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.1in}
  \hrule height 1pt

  \setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}

  \paragraph{My Paragraph} $ $

  \hangindent=0.8in
  Lorem ipsum...
```

I can fix the Linux version by doing something like this:

```
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.0in}
  \paragraph{My Paragraph} $ $
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}
```

After doing that the resulting pdfs are identical. Is there a reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Do you have the same versions (version numbers) of your LaTeX installation on Windows and Linux?

Comment: I have `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)` for Linux and I'm not sure at the moment about Windows because I am not at that work station.

Comment: the difference will not be related to windows/linux and is unlikely to be related to the version of pdftex, but you will have different version of some macro definitions, provide a small complete document that shows the difference and add `\listfiles` showing the file list on each system as reported in the log